# How do I mute videos by default in MPV

Tags: mpv-media-player

I always use `mpv` media player to play media files (video/audio).
But I want that "whenever I open a video/audio through MPV, it should be by default mute".
I tried to add `cycle mute` to the last line of `input.conf` file.
But it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit configuration file:

`~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf`

And add line:

```
mute=yes
```

Now each time You start a video it will be muted by default.

Answer (score 2):

You have

"audio" : "no" or "mute" : 'yes'

as options. Working with the **audio** option I experienced several times that it could not be "turned on" again while the video was playing. So try the "mute" option first.

See [here](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#audio) for the documentation.

Comment: I tried to add both `mute yes
audio no` in `input.conf` file. But not worked. Those option will work through terminal.

Comment: `mute=yes` or `volume=0` should be accepted... Audio seems to be deprecated...

Comment: Okay...........